# Docker - Iniciar contenedores al iniciar docker compose

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

tengo un proyecto con mi fichero dockerfile donde tengo por un lado mysql y por otro lado apache y hay un par de cosas que no consigo hacer.

- Como hacer que al iniciar docker-compose se pongan en funcionamiento estos dos contenedores?
  Ahora mismo hago lo siguiente, ejecuto docker "docker-compose up -d", esto se puede automatizar de alguna manera? Hay algo que me "chirria" porque uno de ellos veo que si que se inicia automáticamente cuando enciendo "docker desktop", el otro no ...
- Para entrar al bash del contenedor no consigo hacerlo por el nombre del contenedor, solo por el ID , para eso hago "docker ps", esto me devuelve el id y el nombre de los 2 contenedores, y entonces ejecuto la orden "docker exec -it id_del_contenedor bash", hay alguna forma de hacerlo mediante el nombre del contenedor?

Os pongo el contenido de mis ficheros.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.4.1-apache

USER root

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libpng-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        zip \
        curl \
        unzip \
        vim \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-source delete

COPY .docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html \
    && a2enmod rewrite
```

**Docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    image: laravelapp
    command: php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port=8080
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - SQL_HOST=db
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=laraapp_db
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_HOST=
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
    mysql_data:
```

Answer (score 2):

Para que el contenedor se inicie automaticamente se usa la instrucción **restart: always** que te faltaba en el contenedor app

Para poder acceder a través de el nombre habría que indicarle un nombre al contennedor **container_nanme: app** y luego seria accesible con **docker exec -it app bash**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    image: laravelapp
    container_nanme: app
    restart: always
    command: php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port=8080
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - SQL_HOST=db
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_nanme: db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=laraapp_db
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
      - MYSQL_HOST=
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
    mysql_data:
```